# LibGDX: Polygonal-Colision detection with informaton about direction

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, game-physics

I've got two polygons in my Game. In this simple case, they are just two rects. Now I want to check collision and if one collision is happen, I want to set the velocities to zero. With `Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons` I test for the collision.

Now, I don't want to set both (horizontal AND vertical) velocities of the moving object to `0.0` since in that case the player for example would completly stop everytime he touches a wall. What I want to realise, is that the player would still "slide" along the wall and only the velocity which is pointing into the wall will be cut of/set to zero.

How can I realise that?

My current code:

```
    Intersector.MinimumTranslationVector mtv = new MinimumTranslationVector();
    bool hasCollid = Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(velocityPoly, velocityObstaclePoly, mtv);

    if (hasCollid) {
        velocity.horizontalVelocity = 0.0f;
        velocity.verticalVelocity = 0.0f;
    }
```

Comment: are your game top down view like zelda or side scroller like castlevania?

Comment: yes indeed that's correct

Comment: so, it's like zelda or castlevania?

Comment: oh, my fault: its like zelda

Comment: the GBA and Snes zelda when you hit a wall/slope the character always go downwards, if you want something based on velocity you can make 8 bounding boxes arround player and make it move to the place it isn't occupied.